# scipy.minimizeでL-BFGS-Bのときだけエラーが出る

Tags: python, scipy

変数の制約付きで関数を最小化するため, scipy.optimize.minimizeで以下のようにL-BFGS-Bを指定しました

```py
import scipy.optimize as opt

bounds = opt.Bounds(#np.ndarray, #np.ndarray)
result = opt.minimize(loss_f, x0_ft, method='L-BFGS-B', jac=f_grad, 
              bounds=bounds, tol=10e-6, options={'maxiter': 100, 'disp': True})
```

このとき,  `failed to initialize intent(inout) array -- expected elsize=8 but got 4`のエラーが発生し,　実行できません

`method`に他のものを指定したときは正しく実行でき, L-BFGS-Bのときだけこのエラーが発生します

解決法など知っている方がいましたら教えていただきたいです

python 3.6.8
scipy:1.3.0
以下出力

```
RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

           * * *

Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =            9     M =           10

At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds
# ここまで標準出力

# ここからエラー出力
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 147, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 120, in main
    options={'maxiter': 100, 'disp': True})
  File "略/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 600, in minimize
    callback=callback, **options)
  File "略/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 328, in _minimize_lbfgsb
    isave, dsave, maxls)
ValueError: failed to initialize intent(inout) array -- expected elsize=8 but got 4
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました. 目標関数とその勾配を返す関数 `loss_f`, `f_grad`が`np.float32`を返していたのですが, これを`np.float64`を返すようにしたところ実行できました.

そうするとエラーの`elsize`はバイト数を意味していたのかなと思います.

対症療法的な解決方法ですが, 参考までに.